# Should I verify email addresses of Google Sign In users?

Tags: email, web, google-signin

I am implementing an email verification service, with the purpose of confirming that the person registering is indeed the owner of that email address (specifically, that they work at the organisation that the email domain belongs to).

I will send an email post-registration with a single-use link in it that will set their status to `verified = 1`.

Users can choose to register and log-in using either a simple email/password combination, or by using the Google Sign In service.

My question is: do I need to verify the ones that have registered with Google Sign In? In order to provide their email address to me, they had to sign in with Google, who then confirmed the address. Is there anything I've missed here, or can I immediately consider these users to be the verified owners of these addresses?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using google sign in there is no need to verify the user.

Whereas if have your own login system, then you must verify the email because

- if the email is not verified then you cannot have forgotten password feature through email
- and also the user might not have actually had the email so anyone else could create the same email and if you have forgotten password through email someone else could easily access others data.